# File path error while converting .md to .pdf

Tags: python, subprocess, pandoc

In a python script I'm trying to convert a `.md` file to `.pdf` using subprocess and pandoc module as given below

```
subprocess.run(["pandoc", "--standalone", "--pdf-engine=xelatex", "/file/path/file.md", "-o", "/file/path/file.pdf")
```

However I get the following error with image files in the markdown file

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'image.png': replacing image with description
```

The image file is in the same directory as the `.md` file, and the same image path works fine when it is converted to `.html` file. Can someone point out what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1):

Wild quess; when you run your python script calling pandoc, pandoc gets executed on some other directory where the images are located. Maybe pass --resource-path that points to the same directory where your markdown file is *or* point `cwd` kwarg of subprocess.run to the same directory where the markdown file resides.

Comment: That's my guess too. It might be more robust to use the [`rebase_relative_paths`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#extension-rebase_relative_paths) Markdown extension by adding `--from=markdown+rebase_relative_paths` as an argument to the subprocess call.

Comment: Thanks, I did add `--resource-path = /file/path/file.md` previously and had the same error.

Comment: @newstudent it probably should be `--resource-path=/file/path` or check what @tarleb said